# How to prevent embedded MongoDB from starting?

Tags: spring-boot

I wish to create some tests that require MongoDB, so I add the following to my build.gradle:

```
testCompile('de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo')
```

However, unexpectedly, this is causing the embedded MongoDB to be started in my application when running from Eclipse?

```
2018-06-21 11:10:53.264  INFO 13748 --- [      Thread-36] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2018-06-21T11:10:53.216-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=5372 port=59475 dbpath=C:\Users\dnaylor\AppData\Local\Temp\3\embedmongo-db-7b002e5e-9dc0-4ac6-8582-93b2e2937ca6
```

If I take out the testCompile, then my application connects to the external MongoDB server as expected.

How can I configure things so that it only starts when I am running a test? I thought that adding dependencies to testCompile would only affect tests, but I guess I am wrong on this point?

Comment: Are you messing around with configurations yourself? Normally the `testCompile` dependencies aren't added by the Spring Boot plugin.

Comment: Yes, I am reading a book that is telling me to add this so that the embedded MongoDB server will be available to my test code. Trouble is, it seems to start up in the main application also and I don't understand why. Perhaps I should start looking at the runtime classpath.

Comment: I think this might be an eclipse thing. When I add the testCompile entry, the flapdoodle jar file gets placed under a "Project and External Dependencies" folder that gets put onto the classpath. Seems like the test compile and compile entries all get put into one bucket?

Comment: Upon further reading, it seems that Eclipse only supports one classpath per project and it basically bundles all the gradle compile definitions together. So this is more a deficiency of my IDE than anything wrong with spring-boot.

Comment: I assumed that what you saw was after building the artifact and launching that, not launching it from your IDE. So is suspect that when you build your jar and run that (`java -jar your-jar.jar`) it won't start the embedded mongo. (You threw me of by stating running in production).

Comment: Yes, sorry. I corrected the question.

Comment: Not sure how to fix it as that is a (longstanding?) Eclipse issue. The only way around it (afaik) is to launch the application through Gradle (which detaches it from eclipse) and use remote debugging (if that is what you want).